# iOS 7 AVPlayer AVPlayerItem duration incorrect in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset

I have the following code in my app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [self.DocDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: self.FileName] isDirectory: NO];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: url];

Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration);
```

This worked fine with iOS 6 but with iOS 7 for some reason it returns NaN. When inspecting self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration the CMTime object has 0's with a flag of 17.

Interestingly the player works fine, just the duration is wrong.

Has anyone else experienced the same issues? I am importing the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After playing around with different ways of initializing the objects I arrived at a working solution:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset]; 
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];
```

It appears the duration value isn't always immediately available from an AVPlayerItem but it seems to work fine with an AVAsset immediately.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, please ask your question in a new thread, showing some of your code and the error/s you are getting.

Comment: I was also using [[AVPlayer currentItem] duration] which returns NaN in iOS 7 for valid media files. In iOS 6 if it returned NaN it meant the file was not playable. Switching to the AVURLAsset idea fixes this.

Comment: Did the Job for me .. THANKS.

Answer (score 27):

In iOS 7, for AVPlayerItem already created, you can also get duration from the underlaying asset:

```
CMTimeGetSeconds([[[[self player] currentItem] asset] duration]);
```

Instead of get it directly from AVPlayerItem, which gives you a NaN:

```
CMTimeGetSeconds([[[self player] currentItem] duration]);
```

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way of doing this, as described in [the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/duration) is by observing the player item status:

```
[self.avPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
```

Then, inside `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context`:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // TODO: use either keyPath or context to differentiate between value changes
    if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that you remove the observer when you change the player item:

```
if (self.avPlayer.currentItem) {
    [self.avPlayer.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
}
```

Btw, you can also observe the `duration` property directly; however, it's been my personal experience that the results aren't as reliable as they should be ;-)

Comment: @user3069232 by "not work", what do you mean? what are your observations?

Comment: It returns nan... I ended up using a combination of AVURLAsset and the AVPlayer status you used here to make it work.

Comment: Ok, looked more closely does work, but not immediately... perhaps not when the video is ready to play.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift version**

You can get the duration using `AVAsset` which is `AVPlayerItem` property:

```
func getVideoDuration(from player: AVPlayer) -> Double? {
    guard let duration = player.currentItem?.asset.duration else { return nil }
    let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    return durationSeconds
}
```

or by creating `AVAsset` from the scratch:

```
func getVideoDuration(for videoUrl: URL) -> Double {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let duration = asset.duration
    let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    return durationSeconds
}
```